# Opencv4nodejs findNonZero exception

Tags: node.js, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for NodeJS ([Github repo](https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/opencv4nodejs)) and I'm performing template matching with multiple matches. Here's my code :

```
const cv = require('opencv4nodejs');

const board = cv.imread('img/chessboard.png');
const blackPawn = cv.imread('img/black_pawn.png');
const blackPawnMatch = board.matchTemplate(blackPawn, 5);
var match = blackPawnMatch.findNonZero();
```

I get this error when calling findNonZero() :

> Mat::FindNonZero - OpenCV Error: (src.type() == CV_8UC1) in findNonZero, in file .../node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/opencv/modules/core/src/count_non_zero.cpp, line 396, status -215

Comment: Since `findNonZero` only works on single-channel images, are your inputs from `cv.imread('img/xyz.png');` guaranteed to be grayscale? And/or, is there an option for `imread` in NodeJS OpenCV to read an image as a grayscale image, like in plain OpenCV?

Comment: I made a mask to have a black and white image and it did work but it's not what I want. I'm super confused. I want to be able to do template matching with multiple matches, do you have any idea ?